# How can I view retweets of my tweet by verified accounts?

Tags: twitter

I've got a tweet out in the wild that had thousands of retweets in a short amount of time. I want to know how to search through the tweet's retweets to find the ones made by verified accounts. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on the Twitter web client by typing the following search query in the search field:

```
@{yourUsername} -from:{yourUsername} filter:nativeretweets filter:verified
```

On the search results, be sure to click the "Latest" tab. What you'll get is a scrollable chronological list of all the verified accounts who have retweeted you. Scroll down the list to get retweets older than one week.

**NOTE:** the **`filter:nativeretweets`** search operator picks up only native retweets, that means you won't see retweets with quotes and you won't see retweets made with an API client. you can use the **`filter:retweets`** filter instead however the results there are "dirty" as it catches also tweet which have your **`@username`** + the word **`RT`** in them.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but you will have to use TweetDeck (or some analogous Twitter service). These instructions are for TweetDeck.

1. Create a column of your Notifications.
2. Under the `Notification Types` menu, only check the box for including `Retweets`.
3. Under the `Users` menu, click the dropdown for `By` and choose `verified user`.

Comment: This filter works, but it only seems to search back a few days. Any idea how to set a date range? Doesn't seem to be included in the filtering options.

Comment: Not sure. You might also try creating a Search column with the following query: "from:<your twitter handle without @> filter:retweets filter:verified" See this page for more parameters: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170322

Answer (score 0):

Any way to search through a tweet's retweets to find the ones made by users with the most followers? I want to know the most "influential" re-tweeter of my tweet.